# Gitlab Runner on local VM with Gitlab CE cannot clone repo

Tags: git, docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci

I have a linux virtual box with a Gitlab CE server.
I tried to configure a runner so I can use CI/CD, but it failed to git clone.

Here the output from the job

> - ...
> - Couldn't find host "my_git_adress".org in the .netrc file; using defaults
> - Trying "My public internet ip"...
> - TCP_NODELAY set
> - connect to "My public internet ip" port 80 failed: Operation timed out
> - Failed to connect to "my_git_adress".org port 80: Operation timed out
> - Closing connection 0
>     fatal: unable to access 'http://gitlab-ci-token:xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx@"my_git_adress".org/"my_project".git/': Failed to connect to "my_git_adress".org port 80: Operation timed out
>     Debug: Remote helper quit.
>     ERROR: Job failed: exit code 1

EDIT: It appears that when the runner is on the same OS/device of the Gitlab server and when it is on another device on the same local network it fails. But when it is on different networks connected to internet it works (but it gets stuck on next steps may be because our bad connection).

Answer (score 1):

Seems like a routing issue between your runner and your gitlab instance:

> connect to "My public internet ip" port 80 failed: Operation timed out

I suggest you login to your runner and try something like this:

`curl "http://my internet ip"`

If that doesn't work you have a routing issue. We'd need to know more about your network setup to be able to help further.

Comment: I get a small html code that seems to redirect to gitlab login page. My runner doesn't have a login and a password configured.

Comment: @Matthew, would you happen to have some references/explanation on how to login to a GitLab docker runner?